# Doctrine 2.1 : Nested queries inside a Join section

Tags: join, symfony, doctrine-orm, left-join, subquery

I've came through a lot of troubles to construct a Doctrine query (in a Symfony project), I've just finished it and it works but I would like to obtain your advices, I'm not sure my solution is the best one.

To make it simple, I've got 3 SQL tables : **Workshop**, **News** and **Comment**. The last two of them are in a ManyToOne relationship with Workshop.

My goal is to display, on one page, a Workshop entity and the related News and Comment entities. To complicate things a little, I only need to display the 5 last News and Comment entities. And, of course, this should be done in just one query (as a troubleshooting, I was using lazy loading till now).

I've managed to make this native query :

```
SELECT *
FROM Workshop w
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5
) n ON w.id = n.workshop_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM Comment ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5
) c ON w.id = c.workshop_id
WHERE w.id = 1 -- Random ID as an exemple
```

After this, I've wanted to convert it to DQL, but this language does not support nested queries inside FROM and JOIN sections.

The last choice I had was to use native queries... After a while, I've been able to obtain this result inside my Workshop repository :

```
<?php

public function getWorkshopWithAllContent()
{
    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);

    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('FON\WorkshopBundle\Entity\Workshop', 'w', array(
        'id' => 'wId'
    ));

    $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('FON\WorkshopBundle\Entity\News', 'n', 'w', 'news', array(
        'id' => 'nId',
        'title' => 'nTitle',
        'content' => 'nContent',
        'pubDatetime' => 'nPubDatetime',
        'validated' => 'nValidated',
        'workshop_id' => 'nWorkshop_id'
    ));

    $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('FON\WorkshopBundle\Entity\Comment', 'c', 'w', 'comments', array(
        'id' => 'cId',
        'title' => 'cTitle',
        'content' => 'cContent',
        'pubDatetime' => 'cPubDatetime',
        'validated' => 'cValidated',
        'workshop_id' => 'cWorkshop_id'
    ));

    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery(
        'SELECT '.
            'w.id wId, w.town, w.description, w.zipcode, w.address, '.
            'n.id nId, n.title nTitle, n.content nContent, n.pubDatetime nPubDatetime, n.validated nValidated, n.workshop_id nWorkshop_id, '.
            'c.id cId, c.title cTitle, c.content cContent, c.pubDatetime cPubDatetime, c.validated cValidated, c.workshop_id cWorkshop_id '.
        'FROM Workshop w '.
        'LEFT JOIN ( '.
        '    SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5 '.
        ') n ON w.id = n.workshop_id '.
        'LEFT JOIN ( '.
        '    SELECT * FROM Comment ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5 '.
        ') c ON w.id = c.workshop_id '.
        'WHERE w.id = 1 ',
        $rsm
    );

    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

So, why redefine almost all the columns? Because if I don't do it, just like this :

```
<?php

public function getWorkshopWithAllContent()
{
    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);

    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('FON\WorkshopBundle\Entity\Workshop', 'w');

    $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('FON\WorkshopBundle\Entity\News', 'n', 'w', 'news');

    $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('FON\WorkshopBundle\Entity\Comment', 'c', 'w', 'comments');

    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery(
        'SELECT * '.
        'FROM Workshop w '.
        'LEFT JOIN ( '.
        '    SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5 '.
        ') n ON w.id = n.workshop_id '.
        'LEFT JOIN ( '.
        '    SELECT * FROM Comment ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5 '.
        ') c ON w.id = c.workshop_id '.
        'WHERE w.id = 1 ',
        $rsm
    );

    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

I obtain this error :

```
The column 'id' conflicts with another column in the mapper.
```

And that's it! My question is now : is there a better solution? Mine is really long and I'm surprised that Doctrine didn't thought of a solution.

A permanent way to solve this would be to rename all the columns of the tables, but I would like to know if there's an easier solution before to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine's join interface is natural but it handles quite a bit under the hood, so simply trying to extend sql will sometimes trip you up.  You don't show the entity struture so I'm guessing that workshop looks like:

YAML (my preference):

```
Workshop:
  type: entity
  << other fields >>
  manyToOne:
    news:
      targetEntity: News
    comment:
      targetEntity: Comment
```

Or annotations equivalent (have to include because most stackoverflow articles seem to be in annotations):

```
class Workshop {
//... << other fields >>
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="News")
 * @JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $comment;
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Comment")
 * @JoinColumn(name="comment_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $comment;
//...
}
```

Try:

```
public function getWorkshopWithAllContent($id){

    $qb= $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('w');
    $qb->leftJoin('w.news', 'n')
       ->leftJoin('w.comment', 'c')
       ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('w.id',$id));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Dotcrine handles matching the id's that you have specified explicitly in your sql.  Check http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html for more ways to refine your query.